# Series expansion of $\frac{1}{(a+x)}$ to obtain $\sum_n a^n f_n (x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

i am confused by the series expansion of 
 $\frac{1}{(a+x)}$ for the general case, where it is not known, wether $|a|<|x|$ or $|x|<|a|$. Can I take from the series expansion [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%201%2F%28a%2Bx%29) just the first two terms of both, i.e. 
$$
- \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a} - \frac{a}{x^2} - \frac{x}{a^2} + \frac{1}{a^2 x^2} - \frac{x^2}{a^3}
$$
Finally, I need an approximation for  $\frac{1}{(a+x)}$ where $|a-x|$ small.

---

Edit: My final goal is to separate to get a completely out of the denominator $1/(a-x)$, i.e. to get an exprassion $$
\sum_n a^{n} f_n(x)
$$

Comment: What is $b{}{}$?

Comment: Please fix the typos.

Comment: Ok, done, thank you for the comment

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider: grrr, and the title ? And the link ?

Comment: 1) taking the two series and summing them does not make sense. 2) do you know Taylor formula? Simply apply it to the point $x=a$